# Flexform maxitems validation

Tags: xml, typo3, typo3-9.x, flexform

I would like to set validation of a maxtems and mintems in my Flexform.
 How can i set it ?

Is it possible to define or should i use IRRE ?

```
<T3DataStructure>
<meta>
    <langDisable>1</langDisable>
</meta>
<sheets>
    <main>
        <ROOT>
            <TCEforms>
                <sheetTitle>TEST</sheetTitle>
            </TCEforms>
            <type>array</type>
            <el>
                <settings>
                    <title>Flex</title>
                    <type>array</type>
                    <section>1</section>
                    <el>
                        <modulElement>
                            <type>array</type>
                            <title>Form</title>
                            <el>
                                <text>
                                </text>
                            </el>
                        </modulElement>
                    </el>
                </settings>
            </el>
        </ROOT>
    </main>
</sheets>
```

Comment: Have a look at TCA https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/. Most of them can be used similar in Flexform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **maxitems** and **minitems** in flex form like below flex form configuration.

```
<el>
  <myField>
    <TCEforms>
     <label>myField</label>
      <onChange>reload</onChange>
     <config>
      <type>select</type>
      <items type="array">
       <numIndex index="0" type="array">
        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
        <numIndex index="1"></numIndex>
       </numIndex>
       <numIndex index="1" type="array">
        <numIndex index="0">My Value 1</numIndex>
        <numIndex index="1">myValue1</numIndex>
        </numIndex>
       <numIndex index="2" type="array">
        <numIndex index="0">My Value 2</numIndex>
        <numIndex index="1">myValue2</numIndex>
       </numIndex>
      </items>
      <minitems>0</minitems>
      <maxitems>1</maxitems>
      <size>1</size>
     </config>
    </TCEforms>
  </myField>
</el>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you Pravin for your answer, but the problem that I have a multiple element not a select input, what I have is multiple objects that I want to maintain it with maxitems, if you see my code you will see that it's an array of elements.

Comment: something like this : https://typo3blogger.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/slider_backend.png